# run 32 bit dll on 64 bit machine, visual studio 2015, web app

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I have a web app that uses a 32-bit dll. When I run it on the "real" IIS server, no problem: for the application pool I set "allow 32 bit" to true.

But when I try to run it on my desktop under Visual Studio, I get an error. How can I tell VS to allow a 32-bit DLL?

I'm running Win 10, VS 2015.

I originally developed this app on another laptop, using Win 7 and VS 2012, so it was possible there!

A commenter asks, "What's the error?" Duh! I forgot to include that. It's "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." I also get, "The type initializer for System.Web.Compilation.CompilationLock threw an exception." I've never seen that message before.

Comment: 1) What is the error? For all we know the error is completely unreleased to bitness. 2) If you go in to Options, Projects and Solutions, Web Projects, what is "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express" set to?

Comment: "Use the 64 bit version" is not checked. Which seemed like what I'd want. I tried checking it and re-building and got the same errors.

Comment: Just to confirm that IIS express is running as 32-bit, can you make a dummy page that prints out the value of `System.IntPtr.Size` and run it? Comment out the use of the DLL that isn't loading correctly to get the page to load.

Comment: I removed my answer, as I noticed I had misread your question. I thought you were trying to use a 32 bit class library in a console/windows application. Sorry.